# How can I type symbols in string

Tags: python

How can I type “” in string.like he said “felt not well.” But it show error. How can I type “” in string python ? I tried so many method can’t make it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You need to escape the characters, also if you share the code and error, it would be easier to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `'` outside the string:

```
s = 'he said "felt not well"'
```

or use a triple `"`:

```
s = """
    he said "felt not well"
    """
```

or escape each character:

```
s = "he said \"felt not well\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your special characters like " or ' by putting a backslash before it like so:

```
myString = "he said \"felt not well\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unicode characters. For example like this:

```
print(u'\u201CHallo World\u201D')
```

This will result in `“Hallo World”`

If you just want to add regular `"` You can either use different quitations
`print('"Hello World"')`
this will print `"Hello World"`

Or you can use escaping `print("\"Hello World\"")`
this will print `"Hello World"`